# Convert to STATA from other program?

Tags: sas, stata

I'm trying to convert SAS code to STATA and am encountering some difficulty. Is there an add-in that could do this for me? While I'm new to STATA I don't even have SAS and am unfamiliar with its rules.

Here is the first snippet of SAS code that is a problem:

```
Libname library 'C:\COFUL\LIB\'; Proc format lib=library;
    Value $RCOMT

    "D43"="NONE"            /*NONE*/

    "Z20"="LIT"             /*LIT
;
```

Comment: Translation has to be done by a person familiar with both.

Comment: @Nick Cox Is there a place where I can learn how to do this? This isn't the most complicated data in the world. Presumably what I'm looking at is someone creating a library, creating a variable, and assigning names based on values?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used SAS. I have used Stata more. If you don't have SAS then I guess you need a book first as overview and then to use the SAS website. Or a local expert. Trying to translate line by line may  be enormously frustrating.

Comment: @Nick Cox This will make me sound awfully naive, but any advice on how to find a good expert on both? Thanks to lockdown my ability to meet new experts relies on googling and this site.

Comment: If your program is less than 50 lines long, then just possibly someone fluent in both may be able to translate quickly, but that kind of question doesn't go down well on Stack Overflow. Role reversal is hard, but try to guess how much a time an expert would need for the task. If it is 3 minutes, you may be in luck, but not if it is 3 hours or 3 days.

Comment: @Nick Cox Oh yes, first do file would take less than a minute for someone who understood it. Second one maybe ten minutes? It's not difficult concept itself, just... much uncertainty for me. Not sure where to ask for guidance. Certainly willing to learn. I'm used to R, somewhat different world to this.

Comment: So, post more code and see what happens.

Comment: One other comment. A proc format should have no impact on a conversion. The entire proc can 'probably' be ignored. Some procs will lend themselves to that, others will not. You can do the conversion but you can't verify accuracy without being able to test each step boundary for accuracy. Formats and informats, in general, will not affect a conversion. Focus on the data steps and the procs that impact data (proc sql, proc sort, proc means, proc summary, etc.). There are approx. 225 procs so I don't know what you have. Data steps should be fairly easy, procs won't necessarily be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing language translation from SAS to something else is hard: there is no getting around that. I have done SAS to C# and it is challenging. You need to know both, as Nick stated. You won't easily find a copy of SAS to use. Check with SAS for a University or Learning edition. That will be limited in the number of obs (recs). SAS is comprised of 2 main things: data steps and procs. These are known as step boundaries. The data step is a very powerful DO/WHILE loop. Procs are a separate beast.

Why would you want to convert to Stata? You would have better luck converting to Python. Read Randy Betancourt's book on Python for SAS users. That would be a start. If you have to use Stata, I am not aware of anyone doing that.

Comment: Stata supports straight python execution: https://www.stata.com/new-in-stata/python-integration/. Recode in python and call it from Stata. The stata developers can comment on that angle but it would seem to offer a transitional method to simplify the conversion.